# Wordpress minimum load with only REST API functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to run regular updates from external app to wordpress website through REST API. But the performance of the API is awful.
I see around the `SHORTINIT` method, that loads minimal WP but it doesn't load rest api either.

My question is how can I make a php file that only loads features I need and also respond to all rest api endopoints?
For example if i make a `/wm-minimal/index.php` how can I make calls to `/wp-minimal/wp-json/wp/v2` which is the url part that wordpress api responds?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this but it's possible that if you minimal includes the red files you could run `do_action('rest_api_init')`

This is a big speculative maybe.

Comment: I am sorry if my questions was not that clear,and also I am sorry cause I am really young on wp development, but I'm not looking to load minimal of whole wp website. I need to load normaly when asking for a Web Page but load minimum when asking for a wp-json endpoint.

Comment: How are you loading "minimal"

Comment: By using define( 'SHORTINIT', true);. If you check wp-settings.php you will see a check for SHORTINIT variable, after which wp stops loading more.

Comment: Ok so you should call do_action('rest_api_init') after you change the define andaybe that will work

Comment: Sure but if I do this in wp-settings.php it will be globaly... I need site to work normaly for visitors and minimal when accessing rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter in the url, add the required files from wp-settings and add do_action('rest_api_init')
Untried.

```
if ( ! filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'shortinit' ) ) {
    define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php';
...
do_action('rest_api_init')
```